# Setup PPTP VPN connection with no GUI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, pptp

I want to configure a remote linux (Ubuntu Precise) to use a PPTP VPN. I can only access to it using `ssh`, so I don't have a graphical interface (neither do I want it).

Some hours googling:

- Guides on where to click in the graphical interface (useless);
- pptp-linux:

  - `getaddrinfo(): Name or service not known`
- nmcli

  - `** (process:5244): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files`
  - `** (process:5244): WARNING **: Error enabling/disabling networking: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files`

Can anyone point me a tutorial, a command that actually works, or any other way to setup all network traffic to go through the PPTP VPN on that machine?

### Update

My VPN service has expired and I will not renew it. I no longer have access to a PPTP VPN, so I can not replicate the problem, nor do I have the need to verify if any given answer solves the problem I described.

Comment: It's easy to configure pppd profile, try google about pppd.

Comment: Hmmm, that getaddrinfo error sounds like you may have made a typo in a host name, or maybe DNS doesn't work on the box. Any idea what its trying to resolve when getting that error?

Comment: It was trying to resolve the server address that the VPN provider gave me, which is not active anymore. I knew the address was good, at the time I was also using it in Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least two good howto about that.

- [PPTP Client documentaion](http://pptpclient.sourceforge.net/howto-ubuntu.phtml#configure_by_hand)
- [Ubuntu Help Article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient#PPTP)

Take a look at them first, please

Comment: I followed the PPTP Client documentation and got the `getaddrinfo(): Name or service not known`